# Android Reverse Tethering

Tags: reverse-tether

What are the latest options to obtain reverse tethering for android?

The [GNIREHTET](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) project has not been updated since August 2020 and does not work for most of the android applications.

Other Android apps that exist and tried is the [Tetrd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.robskie.tether&gl=GB) app that is working but what other means exist or applications to achieve reverse tethering?

Comment: Root your device and manually add `ip rule`/`ip route`. It's been working since ever, and it'll work for ever. No dependency on any third party tool.

Comment: @Irfan Latif , tanks for the advice. I didn't know that rooting allows reverse tethering.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Can you please expound on your comment?  It sounds like your comment could be added as a full answer to this post.  My device is rooted - now how do I go about adding "ip rule / ip route" to create a reverse tethering?